# Remove decimal places to certain digits without rounding

Tags: python

I've found dozen of answers, but non of them is what I'm looking for, I don't want to round up or down, I know that I can round numbers as follow:

```
>>> print('%.3f' % 15.555555)
15.556

>>> round(15.555555, 3)
15.666
```

But I need to get 15.555. Should I use regex?

Comment: Yesss, Thanks alot should I delete my post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution involving `int` abuse. `int` rounds towards the nearest 0. I multiply it by `10**3` to affect rounding. After using `int`, I divide it by `10**3` to get actual results.

It's safer, as it does work with `e` notation.

```
int(15.55555 * 10**3) / 10.0**3
```

Comment: `int(15.55555 * 10**3) / 10.0**3`

Comment: @dansalmo: Thanks, it's indeed better, as it works with negative numbers. Why I forgot about `int`, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9):

Cheeky solution:

```
numstring = str(15.555555)
num = float(numstring[:numstring.find('.')+4])
```